# Input has become readonly when i give initial value to it

Tags: reactjs, input, reactstrap

When I have set the value of `input` field from **reactstrap** to some value it becomes `readonly`.

```
    <Col md="6">
      <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="department">Department</Label>
        <Field
          id="department"
          name="department"
          type="text"
          component={InputAdapter}
          initvalue={type?kpi.department:''}
        />
        <FormFeedbackAdapter name="department" />
      </FormGroup>
    </Col>
```

I am using field from *react-final-form* as shown n above code. Then

```
    const InputAdapter = (
  {
    input,
    meta,
    initvalue,
    invalid = meta => meta.touched && meta.invalid,
    valid = () => false,
    ...rest
  }
) => <Input { ...input } { ...rest } invalid={ invalid(meta) } valid={ valid(meta) } value={initvalue}/>

InputAdapter.propTypes = {
  invalid: PropTypes.func,
  valid:   PropTypes.func,
}
```

This is the InputAdapter Component. Here I set the value to initial value. But after this the field has become readonly. Same issue is with select type inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `defaultValue=` instead of `value=`. Inputs with a value set become [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), the behaviour you are observing.

Comment: please elaborate a little. i am not getting this

Comment: when I a using defaultValue instead of value I am getting value=null

Comment: also it's saying i have to use one but i didn't specified the value attribute anywhere

Comment: perhaps it's getting it from copying input props i.e. ...input